# Infopath in web page, submit data to SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath

We have an internal SharePoint site (not exposed outside the intranet) and we want to make an Infopath form available outside the network. The Infopath form also needs to submit data to the SharePoint site.

I was thinking of embedding it inside a web page. Is there a way to do that or am I out of luck?

Answer (score 0):

if Infopath was created as Sharepoint deployable it needs to be deployed to Sharepoint. I think you would be better off just writing your own form and use web services to submit data to Sharepoint.

Comment: Yes I agree. I could not find any instructions on how to create an Infopath form as self deployable. All of the examples use SharePoint. I can definitely write web services to submit the data